# The set of points that belong to finitely many of given Borel sets is Borel

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Let $E_1,E_2,\dots$ be Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $F$ be the set of all real numbers in finite number of sets $E_i$ (not zero).

> Prove that $F$ is a Borel set.

We tried to look at $F^c$ and conclude from that that its a Borel set, but we got lost in all the unions and intersects.

Comment: Yes, I think the number of $Ei$s is infinite

Answer (score 1):

Hint: a point $x$ is in finitely many of the sets $E_n$ iff there exists $m$ such that for every $n \ge m$ we have $x \notin E_n$.